# How to Edit .XML file on shared Web hosting (Windows)

Tags: asp.net, .net, xml, windows-hosting

I am using Website Panel (Windows Hosting). I have .xml file which contains some setting of sites. I want to do some changes in .xml files.

But I am not able to Reset the .XML File. when i try to edit that file, i got error" another program using files".

I am not able to delete .xml file. when I stop my hosting then I am not able to access this file.

Answer (score 0):

I got Answer of this problem. This is not technical solution but works 100%.

First Login to Panel via FTP.Open pankil.xml file.copy the content of pankil.xml file.now rename the pankil.xml file to pankil.xmll or xmdf. now create new pankil.xml
paste the content.

I did lot of research and this is the most simple and best solution